# What is the default calling convention of static member functions in visual studio?

Tags: c++, windows, calling-convention

What is the default calling convention of static member functions for Microsoft's compiler?
Can I change it by placing WINAPI in front of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default calling convention is cdecl. Yes, you can override this and specify the calling convention. In this regard there is nothing special about static member functions.

Answer (score 8):

The default convention is what ever is set in the project options (C/C++ -> Advanced -> Calling Convention), this defaults to `__cdecl` (command line option `/Gd`)