# Windows Multimedia Timer and PASCAL return type

Tags: c++, c, windows, timer, real-time

I'm writing a C++ program that has to execute a function once every millisecond in order to interact with hardware. Since Windows 10 is not real-time, I found that the Multimedia timer is the best thing that I could use.

**Setup:**

I am on Windows 10 using the Visual Studio 2019 compiler version 19.28.29914 for x86.

I have the following code that sets up the multimedia timer:

```
// Get the minimum timer resolution
TIMECAPS tc_;
timeGetDevCaps(&tc_, sizeof(TIMECAPS));

// Set the minimum timer resolution
UINT wTimerRes_ = min(max(tc_.wPeriodMin, 1), tc_.wPeriodMax);
timeBeginPeriod(wTimerRes_); 

// Start the timer
UINT uDelay = max(min(1, tc_.wPeriodMax), wTimerRes_);
MMRESULT status = timeSetEvent(uDelay, wTimerRes_, (LPTIMECALLBACK)&Foo::callback, 0, TIME_PERIODIC);
```

The `callback` function is declared as a static private member function of the class `Foo` as follows:

```
static void PASCAL callback(UINT, UINT, DWORD_PTR, DWORD_PTR, DWORD_PTR);
```

and implemented as:

```
void PASCAL Foo::callback(UINT wTimerID, UINT msg, DWORD_PTR dwUser, DWORD_PTR dw1, DWORD_PTR dw2){
    // My "real-time" code
}
```

**Question:**

At first I didn't have the `PASCAL` keyword in the return type, and my program crashed immediately when it was started. Some other times, it ran for a bit, but eventually crashed as well. When I added this keyword in, all of the problems seemed to have disappeared. I couldn't find much information about this online, so my questions are:

1. What is this mysterious keyword and why is it needed for the Multimedia timer to work correctly?
2. What other alternatives to Multimedia timer are there for achieving as real-time as possible performance on Windows?

Comment: I'd recommend avoiding casts unless they're necessary. Rather than crash, the program wouldn't have compiled without the cast.

Answer (score 0):

I answer only the first question.
Declaration of `timeSetEvent` says the callback must be of type `LPTIMECALLBACK`:

```
MMRESULT timeSetEvent(
   UINT           uDelay,
   UINT           uResolution,
   LPTIMECALLBACK lpTimeProc,
   DWORD_PTR      dwUser,
   UINT           fuEvent
);
```

Declaration of `LPTIMECALLBACK` says the calling convention must be `CALLBACK`:

```
typedef void ( CALLBACK *LPTIMECALLBACK)(
   UINT      uTimerID,
   UINT      uMsg,
   DWORD_PTR dwUser,
   DWORD_PTR dw1,
   DWORD_PTR dw2
);
```

`CALLBACK` is declared for your Visual Studio version as `__stdcall`:

```
#define CALLBACK    __stdcall
```

Thus `timeSetEvent` requires a pointer to a function that has `__stdcall` calling convention.
When you did not change your [projects default calling convention, the defalut calling convention for static member function is cdecl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7275668/what-is-the-default-calling-convention-of-static-member-functions-in-visual-stud).

Mismatching calling conventions causes undefined behavior. In your case this sometimes led to crashes.

The compiler should warn you about mismatched types, but you did an explicit cast to `LPTIMECALLBACK`, thus hiding the error.

By accident `PASCAL` is declared as `__stdcall` too:

```
#define PASCAL      __stdcall
```

Thus changing your function to `PASCAL` worked. But the right solution is to use `CALLBACK` calling convention for `callback`.

Comment: "*Mismatching calling conventions lead to crashes.*" - more accurately, it causes **undefined behavior**, which MAY OR MAY NOT lead to crashes.

Comment: Thank you for the answer; this was really helpful! I read that a difference between stdcall and cdecl is that the callee takes care of stack cleanup in stdcall, and the caller in cdecl. So by not specifying `__stdcall` for `Foo:callback`, no one cleaned up the stack since the caller of `Foo:callback` expected the callee to, and vice-versa, which eventually resulted in a stack overflow. This would explain why my program crashed after about a minute of execution.